# Hack (PHP) ReflectionClass fails with Map as default property of method

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang

If the signature of a method has a Map collection as the default value of a parameter, an error is thrown when using the ReflectionClass to inspect that method.

```
Cannot use collection initialization in non-collection class
```

The class looks like:

```
<?hh //strict
namespace Acme;

class Foo
{
    protected Map<string, string> $options;

    public function __construct(Map<string, string> $options = Map{})
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

}
```

And the reflection error happens when

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Acme\Foo');

$reflection->getConstructor()->getParameters();
```

The class instantiates correctly when actually using it. I can only create the error using Reflection.

**Question**

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or concept I'm missing, to make this work as expected? I would expect the `getProperties` to return the properties for the method, like it does with any other value/type.

Comment: Interesting. What is your question?

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm missing something to make this work as expected. Any other value/type and the inspection gives me back the appropriate properties etc. I would expect the same behavior with collections.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. Please [file it on our GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues).